# Converting date's default output to Unix epoch

Tags: date, timestamps, time

If I run `date` without any options, I'll get something like this as output:

```
Sun Mar 31 01:05:19 CDT 2019
```

Is there anyway to convert that to what I would have gotten if I had typed `date +%s`?

Comment: Note that it's the output of one implementation of `date`, in one locale (probably something like C or `en_US.*`) in one timezone (probably something like `America/Chicago`). The output could be very different if any of those parameters changed. Do you want a solution that works regardless of the implementation of `date`, locale and timezone, or would a solution that works only in your particular environment be enough?

Comment: An alias? E.g. `alias date='date +%s'` and have it in your respective "shellrc"-file. Or do I misunderstand your needs?

Comment: @Fiximan You misunderstand.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU date (common on Linux) then the `-d` flag will do what you want:

```
% date -d 'Sun Mar 31 01:05:19 CDT 2019' +%s
1554012319
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using an online converter you can find one [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).